# Code running successfully but not showing output in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code.

HTML :

```
   <div id="vis">
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<div class="new_text">');
    ($('#vis').find('.new_text').text("NEW TEXT VALUE"));
```

When I run this code in 'inspect element' I can see the below code as output but nothing is showing in the browser. I want to show 'NEW TEXT VALUE' in the browser,how?

```
   <div id="vis">
             <div class="new_text">NEW TEXT VALUE</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `<text>` is not a valid element.

Comment: there is no html element name `text`

Comment: Ok, now I use <div> instance of using <text> , same thing happened. Now what? @Awlad Liton

Answer (score 0):

`<text>` is not a valid HTML tag, you can use `<div>`,`<p>`,`<span>`... instead:

```
$('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<span class="new_text">');
$('#vis').find('.new_text').text("NEW TEXT VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
$('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<text class="new_text">');
```

use this

```
$('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<span class="new_text">');
```

Comment: Same thing happen bro.

Comment: can u give the jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to change html.

html:

```
<div id="vis">
    <div class="set_texts"></div>
   </div>
```

you do not have `.set_texts` element in your selected div(#vis). so `wrapInner()`  is not adding any div.

you also have extra `)` in the second line of jquery.

try this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vis').find('.set_texts').wrapInner('<div class="new_text">');
    $('#vis').find('.new_text').text("NEW TEXT VALUE");
});
```

<kbd>[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/106/)</kbd>

let me know if you have any question.